# this pattern-matching is not exhaustive in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am new in OCaml and I wrote some code to get the n element of a list

```
let rec n_elem l n = match n with
| 0 -> match l with
    | h::_ -> h
    | _ -> failwith "erorr with empty list"
| _ -> match l with
    | h::t -> n_elem t (n-1)
    | _ -> failwith "erorr with empty list"
;;
```

When I run it using `ocaml` interpreter, an warning generate as:

```
Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive.
Here is an example of a value that is not matched:
1
Warning 11: this match case is unused.
```

and when I run it with:

```
Printf.printf "%s\n" (n_elem ["a";"b";"c";"d"] 1);;
```

it generate match_failure...

Could anyone give me some help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is basically a precedence problem. The second `_` match case is part of the second `match` expression. You can use begin/end to keep them separate:

```
let rec n_elem l n = match n with
| 0 -> 
    begin
    match l with
    | h::_ -> h
    | _ -> failwith "erorr with empty list"
    end
| _ ->
    begin
     match l with
    | h::t -> n_elem t (n-1)
    | _ -> failwith "erorr with empty list"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Jeffrey has very correctly pointed out, it's unnecessary to have nested `match` expressions here. Rather we can match on a tuple of `n` and `l`.

This also lets us avoid duplication of code (the same exception being raised twice).

```
let rec n_elem l n = 
  match n, l with
  | 0, h::_ -> h
  | _, _::t -> n_elem t (n-1)
  | [], _ -> failwith "error with empty list"
```